# Can I use a snackbar inside my service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to get error details from my service call that calls an api if an error occurs.

E.g. if http error that comes back is 422, I want to display a user friendly message.

So, here's my service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://foo.bar/api';
  private body;
  private headers;
  private options;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {

  }

  openSnackBar(message: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, null, {duration: 5000});
  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    console.log(error.status);
    if (error.status === 422) {
      this.openSnackBar('Number already exists');
    } else {
    return Observable.throw(error.message || 'Server Error');
    }
  }

  SubmitTransaction(transactionRequest: ITransactionRequestObj): Observable<TransactionResponse> {
    this.body =  JSON.stringify(transactionRequest);
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionRequest));
    return this.http.post<TransactionResponse>(this.baseUrl + '/transactions/new',  this.body, this.options)
                .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

}
```

I did a console.log and I do get the correct error status number back when there's a 422 error. However, the snackbar won't pop up because I get this error instead:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: this.openSnackBar is not a function
    at CatchSubscriber.TransactionService.errorHandler [as selector] (transaction.service.ts:49)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:24)
    at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:28)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:2283)
```

Is it because I shouldn't/can't use snackbar inside my service (only components?)?

The same snackbar code works fine inside my component but I can't get the error status inside my component.

Here's the service call inside my component class as well:

```
this._transactionService.SubmitTransaction(this.transactionObj).subscribe(data => {
        if (data._errorDetails._status === '201') {
          //do some action 
        }
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.status === 422) { //also tried this inside my component err.status is undefined. However err is the server error message.
        //do some action 
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to bind correct `this` context to do it working:

```
.catch(this.errorHandler.bind(this));
```

Or you can also use these options:

```
.catch((e) => this.errorHandler(e));
```

or local fat arrow function:

```
errorHandler = (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  ...
}
```

For more details see:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: I think you're right. The methods you suggested are not working for me. The first one causes me an error with observable and the second one while it compiles, gives me this error at runtime: "core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable" . I haven't tried the third option yet. But I remember I had a similar issue before and was able to resolve it with self. Let me try that

Comment: You have to return Observable from `errorHandler` method. `if (error.status === 422) {
      this.openSnackBar('Number already exists'); return Observable.throw('something)` but you're only returning observable in else case

Comment: could you take a look at this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091668/validator-is-applying-to-all-elements-in-the-array-instead-of-the-particular-ite if you have time? Thanks!